# An issue with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, three.js, requestanimationframe

While profiling any simple THREE.js animation from built-in examples (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors) I noticed an issue with `requestAnimationFrame`. While the callback itself is executed very quickly (<1ms), there are occasional periods lasting ~140ms, during which the `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't fire. Tested that on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, and it seems, that the issue persists on both. What could cause it and is there anything that can be done to reach stable 60fps without interruptions?

[image]

Comment: `there are occasional periods` - how often? I dont' see this happening ever

Comment: @JaromandaX Once in 20-30 seconds, but there's no guarantee. Have just retried on Chrome several times and during some launches there weren't any problems. Still, the issue is quite annoying, because during those idle periods event handlers are not executed, which adds some input lag.

Comment: I know these sort of timers tend to fire less often when the document loses focus - you aren't clicking away from the page at all are you?

Comment: Yes, if the page loses focus as the result of switching to another tab or application, the requestAnimationFrame gets paused, I'm aware of that, but in my case it happens even if the focus is not lost. Looks like the issue is reproduced if you <repeat>(<press and hold the mouse button>, <move the cursor around>, <release>) a few times. Probably some kind of text selection is triggered, which makes the canvas lose focus?